# Simulating Springs

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am looking to simulate a spring on a rotational joint in Gazebo.  My goal would be to have an arm maintain a position when no external force is applied, but give when a force is applied.  I see the "dampening" feature under the joint, axis properties, but I cannot find a spring feature.  Is there a way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/217/simulating-springs/) by [mdedonato](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/86/mdedonato/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

take a look at this [spring test world](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/a76c10c3543de2357f692799f8d69e52f714e80c/sdf/worlds/spring_test.world?at=john)

it checks equivalence between erp/cfm and spring constants.

see [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qR3kdynLi-0) of it in action.  Left most sphere uses a plugin that simulates spring forces, right 4 spheres have prismatic joints with 0 limits with different combinations of cfm and erp.  The world file contains explanation on the underlying equations.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2012-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1